# Rails: Novice mistake - named a model test.rb - now interferes with Test:module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am making my first rails app, am far into the process, and discovered a messy problem. Early on I named a model test.rb, which is interfering with the Test:Module. It took me a while to catch the problem because I had been running tests on my models, which caused no problems. When I started integration tests, the problems surfaced. Any suggestions about how to go about fixing this? Should I rename the Test:Module? Should I rename the Test.rb model class, search for everywhere in the app it is referenced, and rename them too? Or should I rename the table "tests" the model references?

sample error -

```
NoMethodError:
    undefined method 'where' for Test:Module
```

Comment: rename your test.rb model, fix all the linkage,  and adjust the database table.  I wouldn't go messing with rails Test internals (especially if you're a novice with rails, )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of files you'll need to change depends on how you've set up your development environment, so the simplest solution will be to create a new model with a valid name and delete the old one.  On the command line, you'll generate the new model using the Rails generator with the same definition you used for the current model:

`rails generate model new_model [field[:type][:index] field[:type][:index]] [options]`

Copy any logic you have from the old `Test` model and model test into the new model and test.  That includes any factories or fixtures, post-generation mods you made to the database migration, etc. Then delete the old model by:
 
`rails destroy model test`